# Как узнать положения элемента в списке без использования index (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
s = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"]
print (s)
s.sort()
print (s)
```

надо найти положение элемента "Февраль" после сорта БЕЗ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ INDEX

Comment: Пройтись по списку циклом?

Comment: да, если можешь это сделать напиши комментарий с решением

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"]

s.sort()

months = {
    m: idx for idx, m in enumerate(s, start=1)
}

print(
    months.get('Февраль')
)
```

Ну или так можно проверить:

```py
s = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"]

s.sort()

months = {
    m: idx for idx, m in enumerate(s)
}

print(
    s[months.get('Февраль')]
)
# Февраль
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"]
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == "Февраль":
        print(i)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(next(i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j=='Февраль'))
```